# Help with Gambler's ruin problem, can't solve abstraction

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I'm having difficulty solving this exercise. When I assume that p=0.4 and player A's fortune is 99 dollars and B's fortune is 1 dollar, I can find that the probability of player A losing to player B is 0.33. But when there is an abstraction like this and that 1-p > , I cannot prove that the probability of A gaining M dollars before losing M dollars is less than 1/2.

What i did:

[image]

Here is the exercise:

Suppose that two players A and B are playing against each other and that, on each turn of the game, the probability that player A wins a dollar from player B is p (0 < p < 1) and the probability that the player B gets a dollar from player A is 1 - p. Suppose also that player A's initial fortune is i dollars and player B's initial fortune is N - i dollars, where i and N - i are positive integers. Finally, suppose the players play the game repeatedly and independently until one of them's fortune has been reduced to The dollar. Consider that p # 1/2. So for i = 2,..., N - i the probability of player A reaching state i before reaching state 0 can be determined by:

[image]

**Suppose that the initial fortunes of players A and B are equal to M dollars for each player. Show that if q > p, the probability of player A winning M dollars before losing M dollars is less than 1/2.**